# Struts 2 + error pages + configuration

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to configure a global error page for my struts 2 project. So far i've done the following:

```
<global-results>
  <result name="Exception">/jsp/common/errorPage.jsp</result>
</global-results>
<global-exception-mappings>
 <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Throwable" result="Exception" />
</global-exception-mappings>
```

And in my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
  <location>/jsp/common/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/jsp/common/errorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Struts handles all /* requests. When I'm deliberately trying to go to an unmapped location, I'm getting the error stack trace stating

> There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name
>   checkErrorPage. - [unknown location]

When I'm throwing an error in an mapped action, I'm getting the stack trace again instead of the error page. I'm rethrowing the error as suggested in other solutions on the web, but it's still not redirecting to the error page.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your configuration works for me in a test project. What version of Struts2 are you using? What is struts.devMode set to? Any other details you can provide?

Comment: Steven is right, maybe just a matter of `struts.devMode`.

Comment: can you show struts.xml or struts.properties file??

Comment: this one of those "duh" moments. :). Please shift your responses to answers so that I can up vote and accept.

Comment: @VarunAchar Was the issue related to devMode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration works for me in a test project. Please indicate what version of Struts2 are you using. Also, if `struts.devMode` is set to true, then that would explain why your custom page isn't being used for the 404 responses. With dev mode on, Struts 2 will replace the 404 response with a built-in error page that tries to give you detailed information for debugging.

Note that your custom error page should still be used for exceptions thrown from your actions.

Comment: It'd be better to explain why devMode matters, otherwise it's just a question and not helpful to future visitors with the same issue :)

Comment: Agreed. I'll expand on this later when I have some time.